# How to add value in the second/child layer of an array

Tags: php, arrays, array-push

I'm trying to add a value media_type to every child of the array. The code I'm using is:

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $url = "example";

  $path = $this->get_url($url);

  $popular = ['media_type' => $row["type"],$path];
}
```

Here's an example of the array:
[image: example].

*This content in the array is from themoviedb API. And is opensource.*

Comment: `$popular[] = ['media_type' => $row["type"],$path];` instead of `$popular = ['media_type' => $row["type"],$path];`??

Comment: Acept answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of overwrite array every time just use `array_push` like:

```
$popular[] = ['media_type' => $row["type"],$path];
```

Reference:

- [array_push](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php)